# How to redirect sharePoint Online modern site Page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Sharepoint Online modern site Redirect

Is it feasible to redirect sharepoint page to another site ?

From https://xyz.sharepoint.com/ccg/sitepages/abc.aspx

To https://pweroApp.com/xyz

Below mentioned are my findings and efforts.

1. It can be done in sharePoint classic by simply writing javascript code. But in modern site we can't write code there is no web part that support code.
2. We can redirect the page using "news link" but it only works for home page. It means I can only redirect the sharePoint home page, not any other sharePoint page. When I am trying to do so there is a lag in the redirection.
   For reference: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/02/sharepoint-online-how-to-create-redirect-to-another-site.ht

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread that lists the steps to enable the custom modern script editor web part on SharePoint Online modern page, you can refer to it to install the custom web part, then add your code to the web part.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4b8b3c4-8950-4407-9120-204b80fc35f9/sharepoint-online-best-practice-install-modern-script-editor-web-part-for-sharepoint-online
a.png

Answer (score 0):

To add a script or your own code, you could write a webpart with help of SPFx.
There is a tutorial by Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

Otherwise you could simply put a text field with a link on your site, which redirects to your other site.